# UWP two-way x:Bind to page element not working

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm just experimenting with the new x:Bind, and I've come across an odd problem. I want to bind a slider control to a media element to let the user see/adjust where they are. If I do it with classic binding syntax it works fine.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <MediaElement x:Name="playMedia" AutoPlay="True"/>
    <StackPanel>
        <Slider Name="slider" Margin="50,0" 
                Value="{Binding Position, ElementName=playMedia, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanToTicksConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                Maximum="{Binding NaturalDuration.TimeSpan, ElementName=playMedia, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanToTicksConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Button Name="btnNewSong" Content="New Song" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,50,0,0" Click="btnNewSong_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The slider moves as the media plays, and dragging the slider changes the position in the media stream. All is well.

However, if I change the code to use x:Bind...

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <MediaElement x:Name="playMedia" AutoPlay="True"/>
    <StackPanel>
        <Slider Name="slider" Margin="50,0" 
                Value="{x:Bind playMedia.Position, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanToTicksConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                Maximum="{x:Bind playMedia.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanToTicksConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Button Name="btnNewSong" Content="New Song" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,50,0,0" Click="btnNewSong_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The slider no longer moves as the media plays. I can still use it to reposition the media playback, but it looks like the maximum of the slider is not set correctly, either. If I try to drag it to the end, I get a stack overflow exception.

And, just for completeness, here is the code for the button click event:

```
   private async void btnNewSong_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wav");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".m4a");
        StorageFile storageFile = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (storageFile != null)
        {
            var contentType = storageFile.ContentType;
            playMedia.SetSource(await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read), contentType);
            playMedia.Play();
        }
    }
```

...and the converter...

```
public class TimeSpanToTicksConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = (TimeSpan)value;
        double result = System.Convert.ToDouble(ts.Ticks);
        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        double ticks = (double)value;
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(System.Convert.ToInt64(ticks));
        return ts;
    }
}
```

Does anybody have an idea as to why the first one works but not t'other? The only change I've made to the code was the way I was binding the value and maximum of the slider.

Comment: Do you develop for Windows 10?

Comment: Yes, it's an UWP application.

Comment: What is the output? Does it show any error messages OnLoad?

Comment: Maybe try to see what's it doing in the generated code... Like mentioned here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt204783.aspx "Consequently, {x:Bind} bindings (often referred-to as compiled bindings) have great performance, provide compile-time validation of your binding expressions, and support debugging by enabling you to set breakpoints in the code files that are generated as the partial class for your page. These files can be found in your obj folder, with names like (for C#) <view name>.g.cs."

Comment: The MediaPlayer's `NaturalDuration` property has type `TimeSpan`, so it's unclear what you intend with the property path `playMedia.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan`. IMO it should just be `playMedia.NaturalDuration`. Besides that `x:Bind` generates code that you can debug. You can find it in the `.g.cs` file of your Page e.g. in the `obj\x64\Debug` folder.

Comment: Well, here's what I found. Barptad: No, I get no error messages whatsoever. Depechie, Clemens: Going through the code confirms that the dependency property for the slider position doesn't get updated, but why that is is another question. I don't think that it's anything to do with not binding to `playMedia.NaturalDuration`. The `NaturalDuration` property is of type `Duration`, not `TimeSpan`, so in my opinion it makes more sense to bind to its `TimeSpan` property, which is of the correct type for my purpose.

Comment: [UWP MediaPlayer.NaturalDuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer.naturalduration.aspx): `public TimeSpan NaturalDuration { get; }`, as opposed to [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.naturalduration(v=vs.110).aspx): `public Duration NaturalDuration { get; }`.

Comment: where exactly did you specify, what `datatype` the compiler has to look up? `x:Bind` has to be mapped to a specific `datatype`. Maybe you are mapping to something else, then your x:Bind is trying to map to something, that is not your intended `ViewModel`

Answer (score 1):

The position property from MediaElement is not intended to be bound to like this. DependencyProperties don't have a separate notion of when they fire events vs being able to retrieve the value. The value needs to be correct any time you read it, kind of like with an animated property. You don't want to get into an event change loop for the position property, as that could/would peg the  of the CPU as the value would keep changing, potentially faster than UI ticks.
The Media Transport Controls use a Dispatch Timer with a 1s update frequency, and that is used to update the slider and/or text field. You could use a faster frequency, but 1s is probably frequent enough for most scenarios.